# Polymer 0.5 Working but Polymer 0.8 showing blank page

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

I created custom element in polymer 0.8 but not working blank screen shown i tested it on Google-Chrome, Firefox and Opera. All browsers are updated.
Here is code:

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Polymer 0.8 Test</title>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js" >
<link rel="import" href="my-element.html">
</head>

<body>
 <my-element></my-element>
</body>
</html>
```

and "my-element.html"

```html
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-element">
 <template>
     <div>Hello World With Polymer 0.8</div>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
 Polymer({
  is:"my-element"
  })
</script>
```

Comment: This should work just fine but do you get any errors on the Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved the problem was with xampp now its ok.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your xampp problem was? I'm having a similar issue (using CodeKit as server).

Comment: I just switch to google chrome dev editor its perfect for polymer